# JavaScript syntax error without notification

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript, and I found that there's a bug in my code as I type `length` as `lenght` . However, there is no notification for this bug or syntax error. It took me a long time to debug. I wonder how could this happens? If `lenght` is acceptable by JavaScript?

```
var totalFruit = function(tree) {
    
    let windowStart = 0;
    let dict = {};
    maxLength = 0;
    for (let windowEnd = 0; windowEnd < tree.length; windowEnd++) { 
        currentFruit = tree[windowEnd];
        if (!(currentFruit in dict)) {
            dict[currentFruit] = 0;
        }
        dict[currentFruit] += 1; 
        while (Object.keys(dict).lenght > 2) {
            leftFruit = tree[windowStart];
            dict[leftFruit] -= 1;
            if (dict[leftFruit] == 0) {
                delete dict[leftFruit]
            windowStart += 1;
            }
        }
        maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, windowEnd - windowStart + 1);     
    }
    return maxLength;
};
```

Comment: It's not technically a syntax error. You can assign a value to tree.lenght  so it's just undefined

Comment: You may want to consider typescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly legal to access properties which do not exist on an object. For similar reasons, the following doesn't throw an error:

```js
const obj = {
  prop1: 'val1'
};

console.log(obj.prop2);
```

If a property doesn't exist on an object, but the property is accessed, it will result in `undefined` being returned, but *not* a runtime error.

JavaScript can't distinguish between you trying to access a possibly-existent property, and you making a typo.

If you want to avoid these sorts of mistakes (they aren't that uncommon, after all), consider using something strongly typed like [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), which can turn these sorts of annoying to debug runtime errors into easy-to-fix compile-time errors. (I find TS to be essential for non-trivial projects, it saves so much debugging time.) Another option is to use an IDE with intellisense autocomplete (like VSCode) which makes making these sorts of mistakes harder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. Previously I though React is building on JavaScript, and Angular requires TypeScript. As such, TypeScript is out of my learning plan. Do you have any recommendation regarding TypeScript for React? Thank you.

Comment: Good thing about TypeScript is that it doesn't have that much of a learning curve at the beginning, IMO - most types can be inferred automatically. Worst-case, you can use the `any` type and/or use `transpileOnly` flag when you want it to run just like JS. React is very frequently used with TS, eg `create-react-app my-app --template typescript`. IMO, it's well worth it.

Comment: I might also learn TS as well as JS. Thank you very much for your insight! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

> If lenght is acceptable by JavaScript?

Yes. If you are trying to access a property which doesn't exist, JavaScript will return the value `undefined`:

```js
var obj = {length: 1};
console.log(obj.lenght)
console.log(obj.lenght > 2)
```

> However, there is no notification for this bug or syntax error. It toke me longtime to debug. I wonder how could this happens?

It's not a syntax error. A syntax error is when your code is so "broken" that the parser is not able process it as a valid JavaScript program. Having a *typo* in a property name is not a syntax error (how should the parser know whether a word is correct or not? To it it's just a sequence of letters.)

Whether the typo results in a *runtime error* depends on the context. Accessing a non-existing property returns `undefined` but in your case that wasn't a problem because comparing `undefined` to a number is a valid operation.

On the other hand, if you tried to access another property on the `undefined` value you would have gotten an error:

```js
var obj = {};
console.log(obj.foo.bar);
```

---

Because of these easily to miss mistakes, tools like Typescript and even eslint exist. They try to uncover issues at development time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Because I want to learn React instead of Angular, as such I did not choose TypeScript which can avoid this type of error. Do you have any recommendation about this?

Comment: AFAIK you can use TypeScript with React.

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean use TypeScript as superset of JavaScript , then compile to JavaScript and use React. Thank you very much for you help.